# how to popup jQuery mobile select with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I want to popup jQuery mobile select with JavaScript.

```
<select class="select1" name="select1" id="select1" data-native-menu="false">
       <option value="1">Opt1</option>
       <option value="2">Opt2</option>
       <option value="3" disabled="disabled">Opt3</option>
       <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
       </select>
```

Clicking this to open

```
<p onClick="test()">OpenUp</p>
```

Function:

```
test= function() {
$( ".select1" ).selectmenu( "open" );
}
```

But I got an error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/k3Dz6/

How to fix it? ty!

Comment: Is your code being executed after the page is loaded? If you're using jQuery - are you using the document ready callback?

Comment: i click OpenUp text to open, edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select1` class is also assigned to a `<span>` element that is part of the selectmenu widget that augments your `<select>` element.

Therefore, `$(".select1").length` is `2`, and `$(".select1" ).selectmenu("open")` invokes the `selectmenu()` method on the `<span>` element, which fails.

You can either identify the `<select>` element by id:

```
$("#select1").selectmenu("open");
```

Or restrict the class selector:

```
$("select.select1").selectmenu("open");
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k3Dz6/2/).